# Cross-browser Iframe Height

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a Google form embedded into [my blog](http://tmblrlabs.tumblr.com/contact).
Simplified snippet:

```css
div {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
iframe {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 625px;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1QICJwSJNEjSAGaVz7mWxq0FnrfDMZqOqMn0_iXM0ph8/viewform?embedded=true"></iframe>
</div>
```

It looks ideal on Chrome — neither an extra scrollbar nor unwanted space below the iframe. But that's not true for other browsers, e.g. in Firefox there's an extra scrollbar. What is a *CSS* solution so it looks good on all browsers?

Comment: That's a completely different question. I already know how to remove iframes scrollbars. But if I do it, part of my iframe gets clipped in Firefox.

Comment: ah, right you are. something I would look for, ff and chrome have different default values for properties such as line-height, so when you see a scroll bar difference, it is likely that some default value is causing it. for example, this fiddle scrolls for me at default zoom in ff, but not chrome, since ff's default line height is a little wider: http://jsfiddle.net/kL81z3v1/9